# mongoose, match using upper model field in deep population

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I'm a newbie in MongoDB and mongoose. and I'm trying to create a simple messenger using MongoDB.

Subscription model:

```
const SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  conversations: [
    {
      conversation: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Conversation'
      },
      lastSeenMessage: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Message'
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Conversation model:

```
const ConversationSchema = new Schema(
   ...,
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
);

ConversationSchema.virtual('messages', {
  ref: 'Message',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'conversation'
});
```

Message model:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema(
  {
    content: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: [1440, 'Text too long.']
    },
    type: {
      type: String
    },
    conversation: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Conversation'
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
   }
)
```

I need to retrieve m latest conversations of user and n messages within each conversation when they are written after last seen message. So I used mongoose like this:

```
    let subscription = await Subscription.findOne(
      { user }
      //{ ObjectArray: { $slice: [(page - 1) * limit, (page - 1) * limit + limit] } }
    ).populate({
      path: 'conversations.conversation',
      model: 'Conversation',
      populate: {
        path: 'messages',
        match: { _id: { $gt: 'conversations.lastSeenMessage' } },
        options: {
          skip: 0,
          limit: 50,
          sort: { updatedAt: -1 }
        }
      }
    });
```

the match condition doesn't works in above query. how can use upper model in match condition in the deep population ?
Is it possible or I must try another way?